# How to override Python's random with own generator?

Tags: python, random

In the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) for Python's `random`, it states that one can "use a basic generator of your own" by overriding the `random()` method. Suppose I have a custom generator that outputs a random float uniformly in the semi-open range [0.0, 1.0), i.e. just like `random()`.

- How would I go about replacing Python's with my own?

Further, suppose the replacement is a true random generator built off of a natural source of entropy.

- Does this mean I can use the other parts of the class like `random.choice()` on a given array and make claims that the chosen element is truly random?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the question is whether the other methods of the `Random` class call the `random` method for their random numbers.  That seems unlikely to me because many algorithms don't need real numbers, they need integers.

Comment: @MarkRansom: They do: it's enough to implement only `random`. But it's better to also implement `getrandbits`. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c05a790693b3b00ac7cb5b96ad416ca9d8ecb14a/Lib/random.py#L215-L233

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the documentation does state "Almost all module functions depend on the basic function `random()`", which I find surprising for the reason stated above.  It also says you can replace `getrandbits` as well, but doesn't say if you need to do both or just one.

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks for that link, very illuminating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's `random` module is actually built around the `random.Random` type. Various "random functions" such as `random.random` merely use a default instance of that type.

To create your own random number generator, it is sufficient to subclass `random.Random` and replace its `random` *method*. While not strictly required for basic functionality, it is highly advisable to adjust the `seed`, `getstate` and `setstate` methods as well.

```py
class RangeRandom(Random):
    """
    Example "random" number generator that provides numbers from a uniform sequence
    """
    def __init__(self, resolution=100):
        self._pos = 0
        self._resolution = resolution

    def random(self) -> float:
        self._pos = (self._pos + 1) % self._resolution
        return self._pos / self._resolution

    def getstate(self):
        return self._pos, self._resolution

    def setstate(self, state) -> None:
        self._pos,self._resolution = state

    def seed(self, a) -> None:
        self._pos = int(a) % self._resolution
```

Notably, defining the `random` method is sufficient to make *all* other methods use the same underlying "randomness". For example, random integers as used by `choice` or `randint` will be drawn based on the `random` method:

```py
>>> rand = RangeRandom()
>>> vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [rand.choice([1, 2, 3, 4]) for _ in range(5)]
[2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4]
```

It is worth pointing out that while implementing `random` is *sufficient*, [`random.Random` then uses an internal helper to convert the random floats to random integers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c05a790693b3b00ac7cb5b96ad416ca9d8ecb14a/Lib/random.py#L215-L233); this is inherently lossy, as float has limited precision. If the random number generator permits it, it is advisable to also implement `_randbelow` or at least `getrandbits`.

> #### [random.getrandbits(k)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getrandbits)
>
> Returns a non-negative Python integer with k random bits. This method is supplied with the MersenneTwister generator and some other generators may also provide it as an optional part of the API. **When available, getrandbits() enables randrange() to handle arbitrarily large ranges.**

The undocumented method `_randbelow` must take an integer `n` and return a random integer in the interval `[0, n)`.

```py
class ArbitraryRangeRandom(RangeRandom):
    """
    Example "random" number generator for floats/ints from a uniform sequence
    """
    def _randbelow(self, n: int) -> int:
        self.random()  # advance the RNG
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        elif n <= self._resolution:
            return self._pos % n
        else:
            return self._pos * (n // self._resolution)
```

```
>>> rand = RangeRandom()
>>> vals = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> # explicit int support provides better resolution/spacing
>>> print([rand.choice([1, 2, 3, 4]) for _ in range(5)])
[2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```